# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-02.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect with MongoDB URL using the mongoose module in node.js but I am not able to connect from today morning itself. It was working better until yesterday. Here are the details:

```
URI1: 'mongodb+srv://storeManagementSystem:geZZtcuZOGE2ESCF@cluster0.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net/storeManagementSystem?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

URI2: 'mongodb://storeManagementSystem:geZZtcuZOGE2ESCF@cluster0-shard-00-00.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/storeManagementSystem?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-a7ttlm-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

When I **use the URI1**, it throws the following error

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-02.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0-shard-00-02.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [Array],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
```

When I **use URI1**, it throws the following error

```
Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19)
```

**My approaches:**

1. I have tried searching about this issue but none helped me out. I have also deleted the previous cluster and tried with a new one but no luck on this too.
2. I have added the `0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)` to my network access to access it from anywhere.

**Here are my codes**

```js
function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address()
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
        ? 'pipe ' + addr
        : 'port ' + addr.port;
    ('Listening on ' + bind)
    console.log('API end url ', addr);
    logger.debug({ level: 'info', message: 'serverOnListeningHandler | server listening on port' + addr.port + ' ', applicationrefnumber: "", applicationstatus: "serverOnListeningHandler", lastviewedpage: "" });
    logger.log({ level: 'info', message: 'serverOnListeningHandler | server listening on port' + addr.port + ' ', applicationrefnumber: "", applicationstatus: "serverOnListeningHandler", lastviewedpage: "" });
    let db = mongoose.connect(appConfig.db.uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })
    console.log(db);
}

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    logger.log({ level: 'info', message: 'serverOnListeningHandler | Unhandled Rejection at: Promise' + JSON.stringify(p) + ' ', reason: JSON.stringify(reason), applicationstatus: "serverOnListeningHandler", lastviewedpage: "" });
    // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
})


// handling mongoose connection error
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
     logger.log({ level: 'info', message: 'mongooseConnection | Mongoose DB connection error occured' + JSON.stringify(err) + ' ', applicationrefnumber: "", applicationstatus: "mongooseConnection", lastviewedpage: "" });
    console.log('database connection error');
    console.log(err);


}); // end mongoose connection error

// handling mongoose success event
mongoose.connection.on('open', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        logger.log({ level: 'info', message: 'mongooseConnection | Mongoose DB connection error occured' + JSON.stringify(err) + ' ', applicationrefnumber: "", applicationstatus: "mongooseConnection", lastviewedpage: "" });
        console.log("database error");
        console.log(err);

    } else {
        logger.log({ level: 'info', message: 'mongooseConnection | Mongoose DB connection successfull ', applicationrefnumber: "", applicationstatus: "mongooseConnection", lastviewedpage: "" });
        console.log("database connection open success");
    }
}); // end mongoose connection open handler
```

Comment: Your second URI works and your password is visible to all users here. You should create a new cluster and use that new cluster for all work and delete this cluster.

Comment: Your first URI also works, it looks like you have some kind of a system problem on your computer with performing SRV lookups.

Comment: Thank you @D.SM This is a new cluster I have created for this query, I will delete it after the problem is fixed. Can you let me know what is issue from my side? And is both the URI working?

Comment: I would guess either your system is broken for SRV queries or your node runtime is or whatever library the node mongodb driver is using for performing SRV queries isn't working. Try in your terminal: `dig +trace -t SRV _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net` you should see records like `_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 cluster0-shard-00-00.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net.` printed toward the end.

Comment: Update your mongodb driver and node also for good measure.

Comment: Tried the command ```dig +trace -t SRV _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net``` in terminal and got output something like this ```; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> +trace -t SRV _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.aprzj.gcp.mongodb.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 51 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) in 0 ms
```

Comment: Your DNS resolution is broken for SRV records. Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently

Answer (score 1):

Adding `&ssl=true` to my connection string is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have whitelisted your IP address?

Comment: Yes, I have whitelisted my IP address to make it accessible from anywhere by adding ```0.0.0.0/0```

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting using standard connection string and check if you are able to connect now ?

Comment: I have tried all the way, but it's not working. I have changed some networks, in some networks it's working but in some same issue. Is it possible due to connectivity issues?